# increase legend font size ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to increase the font size in `ggplot2`? I think I need to specify something like `legend.key.width = unit(2, "line")` in the `theme` function, but that is used to adjust the keys in legends, not the font sizes. Thanks!

Comment: I normally refer to `?theme` for these kinds of questions

Answer (score 341, accepted):

You can use `theme_get()` to display the possible options for theme. 
You can control the legend font size using:

```
+ theme(legend.text=element_text(size=X))
```

replacing X with the desired size.

Answer (score 85):

```
theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"),
    legend.title=element_text(size=10), 
    legend.text=element_text(size=9))
```

Answer (score 31):

You can also specify the font size *relative* to the `base_size` included in themes such as `theme_bw()` (where `base_size` is 11) using the `rel()` function.

For example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg, col=as.factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=rel(0.5)))
```

Comment: So what does `rel(0.5)` result in? `5.5`? `11.5`?

Comment: Given a base size of 11, and a 50% size relative to the parent, this would yield 5.5.

Comment: knowing that there's such a thing as `rel` in R is very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 11):

A simpler but equally effective option would be:

```
+ theme_bw(base_size=X)
```

Comment: Careful. For me this changed other font sizes too (e.g. title, axis labels).