# python ggplot legend size

Tags: python, ggplot2, python-ggplot

I've been using the underying matplot lib library to make adjustments that ggplot does not allow me to.

```
p = ggplot(aes(x='meh',y='mah'),data=df)
t = theme_gray()
t._rcParams['font.size'] = 30
t._rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 20
t._rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 20

p = p + t
```

This works as expected. I now wish to increase the size of the legend, which I am creating via adding the `color` argument:

```
p = ggplot(aes(x='meh',y'mah',color='week'),data=df)
```

From [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html), I can see the following argument for editing the legend:

```
t._rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 20
```

Despite there being no errors, this does not doing anything to the legend text size.

Comment: ´y mah´ in your code surely returns an error. there are several way one can change legend font size, one is given here:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20407773/increase-legend-font-size-ggplot2

Comment: Unfortunately that's for `r`.

Comment: sorry, I didn't pay attention to the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After making several tests, it looks like legend font size is actually controlled by the parameter `font.size`. And it also looks like xaxis and yaxis legend font size cannot controlled independently.

(In the image below, the legend that is `color` argument is for illustration purpose only)

```
from ggplot import *
p = ggplot(aes(x='date', y='beef', color='beef'), data=meat) + geom_line()
t = theme_gray()
t._rcParams['font.size'] = 40 # Legend font size
t._rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 20 # xaxis tick label size
t._rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 30 # yaxis tick label size
t._rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 30  # axis label size
p + t
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What version of ggplot and matplotlib are you using? I can't re-create this :/

Comment: matplotlib: 2.0.0b3 and ggplot: 0.6.8 .  do you get a message error or something?